# Publish an iOS app and pay less than 99$/year through "generic publisher"?

Tags: mobile, app-store

So, I have an idea for an iOS app. After some research I noticed that to publish the app at the Apple's App Store I have to enter the [Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) and pay 99$ a year. That's too much for a simple app that I don't even know if it's going to sell at all.

My concept: a "publisher" that officially publishes your apps and also the apps of other developers. The more developers the publisher has the less each one has to pay for that Developer Program. So the publisher would pay the 99$ and its (for example) 99 developers would only pay a dollar each!

Does such thing exist? If so, where can I find a list of those publishers? If not, why not?

Comment: Voting to close the question, as this doesn't relate to programming. Furthermore, if you don't have enough confidence in your own project or idea to front a relatively inexpensive $99, why would a "publisher" want to help you out?  This probably also goes against some paragraph in Apple's multi-page, thick-in-legal-language App Store agreement.

Comment: Most simple apps do not sell at all, so you don't need to "publish" them.

Comment: @hotpaw2 do not sell? What do you mean? Most of them are free? Can you publish an app at the app store for free without paying the Developer Program?

Comment: No, you can't publish an app in the App store without enrolling in the $99 program.  But the majority of published paid apps, especially simple non-exceptional ones, don't sell many copies, if any.

Comment: Did you find any publisher for your app? I tried to ask a similar question twice in SO with no luck.

Comment: Not really, after 3 years I've given up on iOS. On Android you pass less and only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 years and a bounty and still no answer so I will try to give some more insight into the state of things. I will caveat with, this is somewhat of an off topic question for this site, as well as this modified excerpt from the [MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT):

> THE INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
>   ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE INFORMATION OR THE USE
>   OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE INFORMATION.

First of all, as many of the comments have noted, **most** applications just flat out flop at this point.  There is a pretty substantial barrier of entry with the app store model and the sheer number of apps for sale/free is only one reason.

Second, if there was a cheaper way to get on the app store at this point it would likely just ensure even more shovelware.  Apple is already guaranteed the $99 each year from developers so I'm sure they are more then content with this model.  They don't need to rely on the performance of the many (or in this case many many many).

There are, however, a few different ways to publish applications the first **three** are the [officially sanctioned methods](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/):

1. Individual Program ($99 a year)
2. Organization Program ($99 per seat per a year)
3. Enterprise Program ($299 per year Internal distribution aka: no app store)

Now there is also the somewhat controversial method of [Jailbreaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking) which is obviously not sanctioned by Apple and **may not** be legal in your country either.  So far, however, this **is** legal in US and Canada and some others.

The most common "store" outside of the app store is [Cydia](https://cydia.saurik.com/) and some publishers even sell apps here.  This is not in and of itself illegal either, but again it is a grey area and you would be best advised to seek legal council if you seriously want to pursue.

The other downside is that your customers would also be required to Jailbreak their systems in order to purchase from such a store.  So you are likely targeting a more advanced form of user who is also more likely to circumvent any protections you may have on your product.

I am no lawyer, but from what I can tell there isn't anything stopping a publishing model mentioned above.  Apple has allowed for the [transfer and sale of applications](http://venturebeat.com/2013/06/11/apple-is-finally-allowing-developers-to-sell-their-apps-heres-why-and-how/) which is pretty near close to what you are describing.  Theoretically you could come to some **agreement** with a third party publishing entity which would be a paying Apple developer program participant.  They would publish the application with their own credentials and act on whatever said **agreement** specifies as far as payment, royalties, etc.

I do not, however, know of any existing publishers that work under this model.  You would likely then be under the stipulations of both Apple and this new entity in order for approval.  If this model were to catch on it is also very likely Apple would amend their terms of service as they so have the right from time to time.  It would then take further legalities in order to combat any extra stipulations here.

Note: It has also been possible for some time now to [bypass code signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822962/bypass-code-signing-with-xcode-6).  This again is not something Apple wants you to do, but there isn't anything illegal about it, at least in some countries as mentioned above.  This allows you to develop and test on your Jailbroken device.

I hope you find this information helpful.