# Bypass code signing with Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

How do you bypass code signing on Xcode 6 for IOS 8 apps? I used to do this pretty easily following some guides on the Internet on Xcode 5 so I could directly test my apps on my jailbroken iPhone since I don't have the developer account. However, I can't seem to get rid of this error anymore:

"No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found."

None of the guides that I know of seem to work on Xcode 6? Any solutions?

Comment: Why the down votes? While not Apple-approved, this isn't illegal and it is development related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Install AppSync Unified on device from cydia.angelxwind.net repo
2. Open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/SDKSettings.plist
3. Change value of parameter AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED to YES
4. Change value of parameter CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED to NO
5. Restart XCode
6. Set "Code Signing Identity" parameter in "Build settings" (Both "Target" and "Project") to "Ad Hoc Code Sign"
7. Add new "Property List" file to your project with name "Entitlements.plist"
8. Add "Can be debugged" parameter with value "YES" to Entitlements.plist
9. Set "Code Signing Entitlements" parameter in "Build settings" (Both "Target" and "Project") to "Entitlements.plist"

For XCode 6.4 need to do some additional things:

9. Go to "Info" tab in "Target" and copy value of "Bundle identifier"
10. Add "application-identifier" parameter with recently copied value to Entitlements.plist

Enjoy!