# Code Signing macOS App for Testing on Travis CI

Tags: xcode, macos, travis-ci, code-signing

I'm trying to add automated tests to my macOS app on Travis CI, but can't quite figure out code signing.

---

My (private) GitHub repository is set up to trigger Travis build jobs when I push to master.

For iOS projects, Xcode builds/runs/tests the project for the Simulator platform, so no code signing is required for testing (signing with a *distribution* identity is necessary to deploy a build, of course. But I just want to run unit tests).

**But for macOS apps there is no "Simulator": the code is built and run on the development machine itself**.

[This article](https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/travis-ci/) explains how to add **distribution** code signing artifacts to Travis' machine, so it can build/sign a distribution binary for **iOS**.

I have modified the steps explained there to use **macOS development artifacts** instead of **iOS Distribution** ones. The scripts that decrypt my artifacts and install them on the Travis machine seem to work with no problem.

#### The Problem

However, unlike for distribution, *development* provisioning profiles contain a specific list of devices on which builds are allowed to run; in my case, my profile obviously only contains de device ID of my local machine. Obviously there is no way I can get the device ID of the mac that Travis uses, and even if I could, the build obviously runs on a different machine each time.

**How Can I Build and Unit-Test macOS Apps on Travis CI?**

Answer (score 0):

#### TL; DR:

I solved the code-signing problem by **disabling code-signing** altogether (it isn't needed for running unit tests), as explained in [this brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54296008/433373) by [@robmayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff).

#### The Details

I still need code-signing for testing my app locally (it uses entitlements to read from/write to user-selected files and folders). So I created a new configuration in Xcode by cloning `Debug`, named `UnitTest`.

I disabled code-signing and set Development Team to "none" for this configuration.

Next, I created a dedicated **scheme** (shared, of course) that uses the `UnitTest` configuration for build and test. I had to do this in both the App target and the Tests target (I gave up on the **UI tests** because they require Accessibility enabled to run, and the remote machine does not have those permissions). I had to do this because I couldn't get the **xcbuild** tool to use the `UnitTests` configuration.

I haven't quite got my Travis build to successfully complete yet, but I've overcome most obstacles (code-signing included).

Hope this helps someone!

#### Update

I finally got Travis CI to successfully build and test my app. Off-topic, but my code had the following issues:

- Deployment target of macOS **10.15** (latest available image on Travis is **10.14**)
- The project was linking against **CryptoKit.framework** (available only since 10.15!); had to replace it with similar functionality in CommonCrypto.

Somehow the issues above didn't prevent *building* the app, only *running* the tests. I was getting an 'image not found' error for CryptoKit.framework.