# All built iOS apps get error "The application could not be verified"

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-yosemite, jailbreak, ios8.4

When I build the app from my project and deploy it on device for debugging, it keeps getting error "App installation failed", "The application could not be verified".

I tried the solution from similar topic which said "Delete old app on device and deploy again" but didn't worked. I also created new single-view project to test, disable codesign in build setting then deploy, still getting the same error. **It happened to every projects I tried to deploy app on device.**

I'm using Xcode 6.4 on OS X Yosemite 10.10, deploy to iPhone 5s (jailbreak) iOS 8.4. Xcode's SDKsetting.plist was edited to allow deploying (CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO, AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=YES).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trial and error, I finally found the solution!

1. Follow the answer from [Bypass code signing with Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822962).
2. Copy value from key "Bundle identifier" in target's "Info" tab.
3. Open Entitlements.plist, add "application-identifier" key with recently copied value.

Now everything works as expected.

Comment: Worked flawlessly.  Thank you!  Note that for step 2, the target must be changed back to the application target, back from the overall project that was changed by following the StackOverflow instructions in step 1.  Then the "Info" tab will have the necessary "Bundle identifier".