# Create ipa with no developer certificate for remote distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9, xcode7

I have an iOS developer who isn't enrolled in Apple Development Program. I am enrolled in ADP. I need to get an ipa archive from him to install on my iOS device. He can not give me the project so I can just build and run it. Is there a way for him to make an .ipa file so I can run it?

I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822962/bypass-code-signing-with-xcode-6), but I don't have Code Signing Entitlements parameter in Build settings.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your developer can surely create an ipa, even if you don't give him access to the apple credentials.

1. Generate Distribution Certificate from your Mac and Export it. ([Guide](http://www.ironpaper.com/webintel/articles/how-to-share-an-ios-distribution-certificate/#.Vm5Jqxp95cQ))
2. Create Adhoc Provisioning Profile like [this](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204270188-iOS-Creating-an-Ad-Hoc-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile).
3. Send both these items to your Developer.
4. Say to your developer to follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26929524/437146) after archive, in order to create final ipa.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

There are several little programs for signing IPA files, which don't require knowledge of command-line tools or XCode: [iModSign](https://iMZDL.com), 
[InstaSign](http://instasign.uhelios.com), [iResign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign) and others.

Answer (score 1):

You can always ask him for the ipa, then resign it with your developer certificate & provision profile using Xcode codesign command line tool.

Check out: [Codesign Tutorial](http://revolution.screenstepslive.com/s/revolution/m/10695/l/112706-signing-an-application)

Another solution, not recommended in my opinion, would be to export your account from Xcode and send it to him. That way he would be able to set codesign and provision project settings to your developer cert and profile and archive the app.